# Why does else body is not working while coding in php and html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is a table in which fetching data from database table , and in one column if value is available in table then  echo the value else show a button which have a form after filling that form its value goes in different database table  , But action part is not opening only  if body is showing that row not else body

```
$p_query = "select * from files order by id desc limit $page_start_from, $total_num_page";

                          $p_run=mysqli_query($con,$p_query);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($p_run)){
                             while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($p_run))
                             {
                                $c_id=$row['id'];
                                $file=$row['file_name'];
                                $purpose=$row['purpose'];
                                $recieve=$row['recieved_by'];
                                $processed=$row['processed_by'];
                                $address=$row['address'];
                                $contact=$row['contact_no'];
                                $date=$row['date'];
                                $show_status=$row['show_status'];


                            ?>
                                            <tr>

                        <td><a  href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $c_id;?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $file;?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $purpose;?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $recieve;?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $processed;?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $address;?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $contact;?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $c_id?>"><?php echo $date;?></a></td>
                        <td>
```

now in this above `<td>` column i wanted to show this code

```
 <?php if(isset($show_status)){
          echo $show_status;
                               }
        else
        {
  ?>
```

now in this else body i wanted to show a form which is attached  to drop down button , Code is

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style=" padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;"> Action <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:-50px;">
  <form role="banner" class="actionform" action="index.php" method="POST" name="sform"  onsubmit=" return checkvalue()">


 <input type="hidden" name="idvalue" value="<?php echo $c_id; ?>">
  <label  style="font-weight: normal;">Enter Reason*</label><br>
  <input  type="text" name="reason" placeholder="call or letter or filed " id="ureason"><br>
  <label style="font-weight: normal;">Update Date:*</label><br>
  <input  type="date" name="reason-date" placeholder="enter date here" id="udate"> 
    <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit-form" id="actionid" value="Submit" style="background: #3596e0; ">


</form>
      </ul>
    </div>
 <?php }?>                                              
         </td>
          </tr>
 <?php 
        }
          }
?>
```

now problem is  else body is not working , I don't know , Anyone help me please

Comment: how can you wish your else body to work , as far as if condition meets , your else will never execute, `$show_status` is setted above the code

Comment: so @IronyStack how can i  make my else body work  , please help me

Comment: instead of isset check !empty

Comment: @IronyStack , work is done , thank you

Comment: @Raj dont just copy the answer and see that it works... Go back and read up on isset and empty at php.net and understand what they do.

Comment: Why not simply add the WHERE show_status=1 to the query Then only the relevant data needs to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$show_status=$row['show_status'];
```

this statement from your code setting the value of `$show_status`

so your in your case your `if` statements always gets true condition.

```
if(isset($show_status)){ //condition always true
   echo $show_status; 
}
else
{
}
```

if you want to go through else block always then remove that line `$show_status=$row['show_status'];` or just check the appropreate value to approach if statement do not use `isset()` function to do the same.